# Is TimeSync still needed on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, time-synchronization, clock-synchronization

I've always used TimeSync on my servers.  With Windows' built in internet time updating, should I remove TimeSync?  I've never turned off windows time updating even with TimeSync - what is the best setup?

1. Remove TimeSync - it's no longer needed
2. Use TimeSync and leave Windows Time on
3. Use TimeSync and turn off windows time updating

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/4298/best-way-to-synchronise-the-time-on-a-windows-2008-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a domain DON'T use 3rd party time-sync's !!!!
The domain will take care of it and it better be the only one that handles time-sync for the Windows boxes.
(Domain computers need to be on the same (or very close) clocks in order for authentication to work properly.)
Non-Domain Windows PC's can be set to use the domain controller as time-source (each DC acts as SNTP time-server automatically).

3rd party of MS own doesn't really matter. As of XP/W2K3 the MS time-sync works just fine. It's just a bit basic, but good enough.

Bear in mind that for any NTP or SNTP based time-sync you need access to the time-servers.
By default this is usually "time.windows.com" (Microsoft) or "ntp.pool.org" (anything else) on the internet. If the company firewall doesn't allow this you will have to use an internal time-source and configure the software accordingly.

If you are not sure if there is an internal time-source available go talk to the network administrators. They need one too and usually have a good time-infrastructure ready for use.

Answer (score 2):

On an AD domain member, I would definitely use only w32time.  On a non-domain server, it's probably a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

If you thought you needed timesync before, the same reasons still apply so then yes.  Windows has always had built in internet time updating (at least from 2k3 on - I'm pretty sure 2000 did as well) so I've never seen a need to run a 3rd party tool.  The time structure hasn't changed in 2008.